# Understanding indirection through pointers and taking address

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, unary-operator

In the Standard [N1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf), `Section 6.5.3.2#3` the following is specified (emp. mine):

> If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that
>   operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both
>   were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply
>   and ***the result is not an lvalue***.

Later on the section `6.5.3.2#4` specifies:

> If the operand points to a function, the result is a function
>   designator; if it points to an object, ***the result is an lvalue***
>   ***designating the object***.

This two sections look contradictory to me. The first on I cited specifies that the `result is not an lvalue`, but the second one specifies that the result of indirection operator is an lvalue.

Can you please explain this? Does it mean that in case of object the operators `*` and `&` does not eliminate each other?

Comment: The omission of the preceding two sentences in your first citation isn't doing any favors to convey what is actually being covered by that part of the standard. The specific case detailed by that cite is concerning the form `&*var`, where `var` is a pointer-to-type referring to some object,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 6.5.3.2#3 talks about the unary `&` operator and the 6.5.3.2#4 talks about the unary `*` operator. They have different behaviors.

Elaboration ([from comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755753/understanding-indirection-through-pointers-and-taking-address/53755804?noredirect=1#comment94364702_53755804)):

The point is that unary `&` does not result in an lvalue, even in the case where it is considered omitted because it immediately precedes unary `*` in a dereference context. Just because both operators are considered omitted doesn't change the fact the resulting expression is not an lvalue; the same way it would not be if a solo unary `&` were applied.

```
int a; 
&a = ...;
```

is not legal (obviously). But neither is

```
int a; 
&*a = ...;
```

Just because they are considered omitted doesn't mean `&*` is lvalue-equivalent to solo `a`.

Comment: The quote from `6.5.3.2#3` I provided talks about omission `&` and `*`, not just about `&`. Percisely about `&*var` where is a pointer to say `int`. The `6.5.3.2#4` says that the result of  `*var` is an `lvalue`.

Comment: @St.Antario I'm not sure where you're getting at with that. the point is, an expression like `&*var` does not yield a lvalue which, otherwise, could have been used as the LHS of the assignment operator, for example.

Comment: @St.Antario the point is that unary `&` does not result in an lvalue, even in the case where it is considered omitted because it immediately precedes unary `*` in a dereference context. I.e. just because both operators are considered omitted doesn't change the fact the resulting expression is not an lvalue; the same way it would not be if a solo unary `&` were applied. I.e. `int a; &a = ...;` is not legal (obviously). But neither is `int a; &*a = ...;`. Just because they are considered omitted doesn't mean `&*` is lvalue-equivalent to solo `a`.

Comment: @WhozCraig beat you by ~5 seconds. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I was going to put all of that in an answer, but honestly was on the fence to see if you embellished yours first. It was apparently good enough for selection for the OP, so I didn't bother.

Comment: @WhozCraig but sir, I'm not going to get that elaboration go to waste. Since you have made the effort of putting that into words (maybe in a comment, who cares)..I'll add that in my answer itself. It's too valuable to be sitting in comments.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Snipe away. I'd be lying if I said i've never done said-same. Comments are frequently a wealth of tasty content.

Comment: @WhozCraig Done, with a bit of change, with your permission. :)